# Python Curve Shifiting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to shift the green curve below upward (or downward) along Y-axis depending on a given P1 point at day 4. I would like to know how I can do that in order to predict a P2 point, based on the original curve if it was shifted.

I know that the green curve has the formula:

`0.000371 x^3 - 0.01274 x^2 + 0.1428 x - 0.02804`

I need to solve two points:

**1 - How to shift the green curve based on P1.**

**2 - Calculate P2 as a projection of the green curved shifted.**

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
y = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.38,0.41,0.46,0.475,0.478,0.486,0.489,0.493,0.49,0.495,0.498,0.511,0.5124,0.53]
plt.plot(x, y, 'x-')

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', label='original data')
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, label='fitted line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print(f)


# function to be defined :
p1 = 0.38 
p2 = findP2(f,p1) # to build
print(p2)
```

I hope someone can help me, please!

:)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To shift the green curve, you need first to shift your data. From your code, I guess that variable `p1` is the y-coordinate of point P1.

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(y) - y[3] + p1
```

2. `p2` seems just to be the value of your polyfit at the x-coordinate of P2.

Please give me more information if this answer is not correct.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constant to your 'y' data to shift the data upwards/downwards. But essentially you're just adding a constant to fitted function. So as 'z' is a fitted polynomial you can add the shift to the constant term of this polynomial (I do not know if this is z[0] or z[3], lets assume z[3]). So 
`z[3] +=  (y[3] - p1)`. The shift is the same over the whole function, so calculating p2 is easily done by subtracting the shift from the y value, `p2 = y[15] - (y[3] - p1)`.